# Skype behaviour in the Windows 7 Superbar

Tags: windows-7, skype, superbar

The new version of  Skype is always stuck on my Super-Bar(unless i exit the program), which is really annoying. There is not option to minimize it to the tray at least in Skype options. Has anyone had this problem and figured out how to minimize it to the tray?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following website tells about how to minimize Skype to tray.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/01/23/how-to-minimize-skype-to-windows-7-system-tray-notification-area/

> 1.Exit or quit from Skype program.
>
> 2.Right click on Skype icon on Desktop or Skype shortcut in Start Menu, and select Properties.
>
> 3.Go to Compatibility tab.
>
> 4.Under “Compatibility Mode’ section, check and tick the checkbox for Run this program in compatibility mode for: option.
>
> 5.In the below drop-down box, select Windows Vista (Service Pack 2).
>
> 6.Click OK.
>
> 7.Start the Skype program, and now it should minimize to system tray.

Comment: Thanks! just faced the same problem and the above solution did the trick.

Comment: I tried this with v5.0.3.111 and Skype would not load.