# How does "Compatibility Mode" in Windows 7 affect the application?

Tags: windows-7, skype, compatibility

**Background:** *Based on [the answer](https://superuser.com/questions/121751/skype-behaviour-in-the-windows-7-superbar/121765#121765) given to this question: "Skype behaviour in the Windows 7 Superbar" ...you can get Skype to minimize to the system tray (rather than the task bar) by running it in compatibility mode. (red flags going off in my head)*

That's the *behavior* that I want but **what does "compatibility mode" do to the executing application**?

I am concerned about changing the execution mode of an entire (important) application to a previous generation just to alter the user interface behavior a bit.

So, what does compatibility mode actually do internally? What are the *disadvantages*, as in "how could the application (Skype) suffer?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what Microsoft has to say about [Understand Application Compatibility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449431%28WS.10%29.aspx) just a generalized answer not directly targetted to skype but it covers most of the aspects of why compatibility mode was needed and its advantages and flaws.